# About renew iOS certificates

Tags: ios, objective-c, certificate

I'm going to renew my iOS certificate and I have questions about that :

- Do I have to re-publish my apps on the App Store with the renewed certificate ?
- Do I have to re-create all the provisioning profiles for my tested apps ?
- Do I have to re-save my devices or are they kept in memory ?

Comment: The answer is **NO** for all three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I have to re-publish my apps on the App Store with the renewed certificate ?

No.

> Do I have to re-create all the provisioning profiles for my tested apps ?

You will have to recreate provisioning profiles to submit new apps to the store. For adhoc test apps in the wild, they will continue to function until the expiry date of the old certificate.

> Do I have to re-save my devices or are they kept in memory ?

If you mean the list of devices in the provisioning portal (now known as "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles"), they will be kept as they are.